# Ame method for all UIButtons

Tags: ios, xcode

I have many UIButtons which are linked to codes, but I wanted to have a method which works for all UIbuttons without connecting the method to the button, to play a sound when each button is pressed. Is there a way to detect when a general UIbutton is pressed? even if not linked to any code?

Comment: One option is to subclass the UIButton and implement this. Use the subclassed button in your project then.

Comment: Create a subclass of `UIButton` and in its `init` method you can add an action to play a sound when the button is pressed. Then when you use this custom button in your project it should work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my comments, one option is by subclassing `UIButton`. You can create a subclass of `UIButton` and implement its `init` methods to add an action which will play a sound when pressed. This would be like the normal button actions but the target will be this custom subclass.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    if (self=[super initWithFrame:frame]) {
        [self addTarget:self action:@selector(playSound) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)playSound {
  //play sound
}
```

Then use the button as,

```
CustomButton *aButton = [[CustomButton alloc] initWithFrame:aFrame];
```

If you are using xib or storyboard, you can change the class of button object from `UIButton` to `CustomButton`.

Comment: and if the buttons are added in the user interface?

Comment: Change its class from UIButton to CustomButton in xib or storyboard. I am sure there should be an option to change that.